# New race of humans found

Tags: warfare, humans, species

Let's say a new race of humans appeared some 300 years ago.
They spread across the globe and now they reveal themselves to the rest of humanity.
They lived mixed with normal humans for the entire time.
This race has around 10.000.000 members.
They know about their race, but they kept their existence a secret.Until now.

There are two notable differences between them and the mainstream human:

1)they are way smarter than the average person.Think an average iq of 150;

-also far more creative from all points of view;

2)they have more stamina, for example they only need 4 hours of sleep per night.

That's it.There are no other notable differences between normal humans and this race.They don't have supernatural powers, they don't have some weird 6th sense, physically they have the same power as the average person, they don't heal superfast etc.Their appearance is normal.

For a decade after "reveal", humans and them cohabitated relatively peacefully, in the same society.
However, given their characteristics, they are way successful than the average Joe.
It seems that every celebrity, entrepreneur, inventor is a member of this race!

Soon enough, normal humans start believing that they plot to conquer them and start rounding them up and taking them to extermination camps(a la Hitler).
A conflict arises between this race and the rest of humanity.Who would have the best chance of winning this conflict/war?

Edit: 
how they appeared is not relevant.

Why they revealed themselves is also irrelevant.

Their appearance may look normal, but their biology is slightly different.
This changed biology has the aforementioned consequences.

Comment: Can they interbreed with humans? If so then why haven't their superior genes spread through the human population? Do they have any drawbacks to compensate for the advantages?

Comment: Is there any way to detect them or tell them apart from normal humans? Are those tests fast or slow?

Comment: They can interbreed, but the descendants are not fertile.

Comment: Differences are detectable with lab tests.

Comment: How would they identify each other and know their numbers? They seem like exceptional people, but if I were one I'm not sure that I would notice very quickly at all that another person is fundamentally different than another.

Comment: They have groups that communicate between one another.

Comment: If they are so smart, why did they reveal their existence?

Comment: speciation isn't usually that sudden -- usually it's a gradual process, as populations that are separated from one another slowly diverge. It generally isn't the case that one generation is the same species and two or three generations later they can't interbreed and produce fertile offspring. So not sure how this could happen, or why there was no interbreeding for long enough for speciation to occur.

Comment: Note: my above comment may be irrelevant, since a storyteller/worldbuilder can start wit any premise they like and then work out the 'what if' implications. If it doesn't matter to you whether the premise is plausible or not, then please ignore my previous comment :) You didn't use the 'science-based' or 'reality-check' tags, so my comment may be beside the point.

Comment: If they can't interbreed with humans, then they aren't human.

Comment: Can you clarify: They are their own species, so for 300 years (about 9 generations), they have been interbreeding only (so, it's not like one just "showed up" in Japan, and another in Tunisia, etc.) - if so, where is their source: USA, etc., even though I understand they may have migrated.

Comment: @shiningcartoonist - it seems that to be one, you must have both parents are also, so maybe they pass it down from generation?

Comment: The most implausible thing here is that all celebrities have an IQ of 150.

Comment: @Mikey they come from a single place, an island in the Indian ocean and they migrated. They didn't showed up one in US, another one in Japan etc.

Comment: @Alex - okay that's helpful; it does however mean that from your first two humanoids, every single couple must reproduce (say at age 20?) 4 or more kids to reach about 10,000,000 in 300 years (15 generations).  Just FYI

Comment: I don't think 150 IQ is enough to offset the massive number disparity between 10 million and 8 billion. That's nearly 1000 to 1. Hiding would be their best bet.

Comment: @fredsbend: maybe.but couple that with their stamina and it's like having 20-30 million gifted people instead of 10 million in terms of productivity.

Comment: Read the book "extinction". I will add a Link when I am home again. Great Story, and it covers your case (but only with two superhumans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your new race would have a major problem in that it is spread out across an almost completely hostile world, without any kind of stronghold or borders to defend. In a sudden, open conflict with the massively more numerous humans, it would only be a matter of time before they were mostly killed or rounded up. Having slightly better intelligence and stamina than normal humans would not be a big enough advantage to overcome the huge disparity in numbers, once they are revealed.

Possibly they have been preparing for this eventuality and have stockpiled weapons and materiel somewhere but they would have to very quickly gather in a specific area, take it over and prepare to defend it. This of course leaves them vulnerable to WMDs and nuclear attacks unless they have also made preparations for this.

Another option is that the new race has manipulated politics and industry, putting key people in place such that they can enact some kind of coup in say Russia or the United States, thus taking over a large, resource rich area with intact war capability. Assuming that most of the new race moves to this new territory they might be capable of subduing and controlling the local human population and presenting enough of an external threat that the remaining human-controlled areas cannot win a war against them (especially if they have control of nuclear assets), thereby forcing a Cold War style stalemate.

Comment: Yeah, preparing "just in case" and getting a hold of nuclear weapons is pretty much what I had in mind also.
But occupying a large territory like Russia or the US will be pretty difficult.Israel seems like an easier target though.Kinda ironic.

Answer (score 5):

This is not fiction. Our world is ALREADY that way... Out of the ~8 Billion people on this planet, it is clear that some people are just smarter and need less sleep.
Actually, 10 Million is a pretty small number. The top 1% of humanity's intelligent people is about 80 Million people. 
Even if you look at IQ - that's how it's measured. IQ score isn't an absolute measure. An IQ of 150 means you are in the top 0.1% of intelligent people (I don't actually know the exact bell curve that is used to score IQ).
And mass genocide has happened before.

Look at the Ashkenazi Jews. They are considered to top the IQ charts and it's those Jews that were subject to the holocaust. Look at their Nobel prizes, you can argue they invented a lot of stuff.
(I'm using the Ashkenazi Jews example to show an example of genocide, not an example of superior intellect)

The European Jews did not save themselves, they were lucky Hitler also threatened the rest of the world. The extermination of Jews in Europe was prevented as a side effect of the Allied victory. It was not the Allied's goal and the Jews had virtually no effect on the outcome of WWII.

But 10 Million can simply not control the vast majority of people. We are not ruled by intelligence. Our leaders employ our fear and aggression to rule us. Those smart people will have no chance but to hide and pretend they are regular.
If the regular people have a way to determine which race a person belongs to, they will eventually find all people from that race and exterminate them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32412/discussion-on-answer-by-draxdomax-new-race-of-humans-found).

Comment: IQ is usually like this. 100 points is average, 50th percentile. Every ten points is one standard deviation. So an IQ of 150 is 5 standard deviations above the average.

Answer (score 2):

The race would manipulate others to fight for them rather than fighting for themselves. If they had enough money and power by the time the war begins they should survive.

Comment: The only answer that actually targets the question (and I provided two answers here)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial specification is of:
10,000,000 people with intelligence matching the top 2% of humanity. That's not a big advantage to them.

I am now providing an answer with a higher specification. Let's say they are 10,000,000 people with intelligence rated at the top 0.00001% of humanity. Basically, they are thousands of times smarter than the smartest human.

In that case, they would use automation and the computer-based technology we rely on. Via viruses, they would have control over our computers, communication, satellites, etc...

They will build deadly robots to compensate for their outnumber-ence. Such robots will be entirely autonomous and wield high precision rifles/laser and explosives as well as nukes.
Those robots will also self-repair, self multiply, self mine-for-resources and self coordinate.

After a bloody war in which humanity is overpowered by those robots, the superior race will have gained enough territory to establish their own autonomy, where they are safe from invasions and prosecutions. They will be isolated like North Korea but they will have the power to reach out and take what they need from the other countries if they do not cooperate through trade.
Their technology will be impervious to hacking or stealing.

Answer (score 0):

Our own Ancestors were probably in a similar situation when they entered Europe during the last Ice Age, being outnumbered and physically inferior to the Neanderthals and Denisovans who were already present in Europe and Asia at the time.

However our Ancestors were much more social (archeology seems very clear that Homo Sapiens lived and moved in larger  bands than the Neanderthals, and since the Denisovans were apparently similar to the Neanderthals, it can be inferred that they were also less social than the Ancestors), so they used their ability to link up in larger numbers to quickly swarm over desirable real estate, gather and trade desirable goods, and even apparently seduce Neanderthal and Denisovans (modern Human DNA has traces of Neanderthal and Denisovan DNA to this day).

A smarter breed of "humans" would probably be able to do the same, unless part of the change was to make them sociopathic and unable to make bonds with other beings. (Even that might not stop them, successful sociopaths model other people to seduce them, manipulate them or even prey upon them).

By the time the mundane humans figured out what was happening, the "new" people would be well entrenched in society, interbreeding with normal people and using their enhanced intelligence to manipulate things behind the scenes. Even if in your scenario people are becoming paranoid that the "successful" businessmen, political leaders, celebrities etc. were all "new" humans, the *real* "new" humans could be setting up fall guys as fronts to attract attention, while remaining safe at home or working quietly behind the scenes. Mundane humans would hold their witch hunts but only be catching the people the new humans *want* to be caught.

In the end, the new humans would be well hidden in society after the witch hunts had burned out, and would simply be more careful in how they did their work, while also working to increase their numbers and spreading their genes in the human gene pool.

Comment: Your second mention of sociopaths confuses sociopathy with psychopathy. Psychopaths manipulate people to get what they want. Sociopaths don't care enough to try. They are similar in that both cannot form healthy relationships.